# Exclude certain DataSource(s) from HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-jpa

I have a project with 2 DataSources. One is for PostgreSQL and other is for ClickHouse. No problem so far.

I intend to use ClickHouse with native SQL via JDBC only.

But I would like to use JPA based repositories with PostgreSQL datasource. And if I add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency, <s>`HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` kicks in for **ALL** registered DataSource beans</s>. ClickHouse is not a transactional relational DB and its JDBC implementation is very limited and basic, never intended for use with Hibernate. **So my question is: is it possible to use `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` for both datasources, but somehow tell `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` to configure just with PostgreSQL datasource?**

I would still like to use auto configuration goodies like DataSource configuration with Connection pooling with practically just a few lines in properties file. I know I can exclude `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` completely and configure everything (entityManager, transactionManager, ...) on my own, but I would like to avoid that if possible. Just telling it to avoid configuring ClickHouse datasource seems way more elegant.

---

## Update

Some of my assumptions were incorrect. Read the accepted answer. It is very insightful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataSourceAutoConfiguration` will only kick in if you do not define any beans for the datasource .It will then create and configure only one datasource based on the setting configured in the `application.properties`. That means if you need to create two datasources ,it cannot be used for such case and you have to manually define both datasources. You can refer to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-two-datasources) for how to configure multiple datasources by simulating what are done by the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`.

On the other hand, `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` will only kick in if there is only one `Datasource` bean defined (see the [codes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/ce653059c8144504a2daa6b54073ad05d5719977/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.java#L64) as it is marked with `@ConditionalOnSingleCandidate`)

And from the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnSingleCandidate.html) of `@ConditionalOnSingleCandidate`:

> @Conditional that only matches when a bean of the specified class is
>   already contained in the BeanFactory and a single candidate can be
>   determined.
>
> The condition will also match if multiple matching bean instances are
>   already contained in the BeanFactory but a primary candidate has been
>   defined; essentially, the condition match if auto-wiring a bean with
>   the defined type will succeed.

That mean you can simply mark the DataSource bean that you define for the PostgreSQL with `@Primary` and `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` should only consider it but ignore others.