# Is it possible to use JDBC Template and JDBC MySQL at the same time?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, h2

I’m currently building a simple CRUD based app, and I’m done with the basic stuff, like creating a form with a title, date, description etc, editing or deleting a post etc. So now I’m trying to add an image upload function as well. (I’m using Windows 10 as my OS)

At this moment, I’m studying a tutorial of the following URL

https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-jpa-hibernate-mysql-database-example/

, and when I take a look at

## Configuring the Database and Multipart File properties

section, it explains what statements are needed to configure the database and multipart file properties, but when I added the tutorial page’s sample it caused conflict.

The below is how my `application.properties` file looks like.

（The line `“## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties”` and after that is the part that I copied and pasted from the tutorial, and above that is the original code before adding the tutorial’s)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/file_demo?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= callicoder

## Hibernate Properties

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

## Hibernate Logging
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL= DEBUG

## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
```

The part that’s causing the conflict is the following.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource.username=sa

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/file_demo?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username= root
```

I assume that the reason for the conflict is that I’m trying to use JDBC H2 database and JDBC MySQL at the same time. At first I thought that commenting out my original configuration like below would solve the problem,

```
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
#spring.datasource.username=sa
#spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

, but after this I couldn’t run the program probably because there is a part where I use JDBC Templace like below.

## [ReportDaoImpl.java]

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Repository
public class ReportDaoImpl implements ReportDao {
    
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; 
    
    @Autowired
    public ReportDaoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate; 
    }

    @Override
    public List<Report> findAll() {
        String sql = "SELECT report_id, title, threat_level, report_date, description, img_path, "
                            + "user.user_id, user_name FROM report "
                            + "INNER JOIN user ON report.user_id = user.user_id";
        
        List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql); 
……
```

My biggest question is, how can I integrate the tutorial’s “upload an image” function to my basic CRUD app without causing a conflict in configuration?

Should I give up using JDBC H2 Database and JDBC Template and use something else that is compatible with the JDBC MySQL part that I’m taking from the tutorial? In other words, in order to integrate the tutorial’s image upload function, should I fundamentally restructure my code in `ReportDaoImpl.java` file (and maybe even other files as well?), or would there be a simple way to resolve the configuration conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to give away any of your Databases if you intend to use them for absolutely necessary reasons. Spring doesn't DataSourceAutoConfiguration can't differentiate between the two configs in the property file for the simple fact that the property file is a key-value pair map. And hence it would override the configs.

The easiest way to resolve this is:

1. Create separate keys for different datasources as under:

```
## Your Primary Data Source
spring.datasource-primary.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource-primary.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource-primary.username=sa
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

## Your Secondary Data Source
spring.datasource-secondary.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/file_demo?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource-secondary.username= root
spring.datasource-secondary.password= callicoder
```

2. Add a DataSourceConfig as under

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Configures the Spring-managed resources for Common Services/Utils.
 */
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    /**
     * Primary DataSource (Meaning the one that is your parent transaction manager)
     */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource h2DataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource-primary.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource-primary.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource-primary.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource-primary.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * @usage Autowire this in your JPA Repositories using
     *      @Autowired
     *      JdbcTemplate h2JdbcTemplate;
     */
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate h2JdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(h2DataSource());
    }

    /**
     * Secondary DataSource (Meaning the one that can cause the parent transaction to roll-back on exception)
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource-secondary.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource-secondary.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource-primary.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource-secondary.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * @usage Autowire this in your JPA Repositories using
     *      @Autowired
     *      JdbcTemplate mysqlJdbcTemplate;
     */
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate mysqlJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(mysqlDataSource());
    }
}
```

3. Use in right JdbcTemplate in your repository classes

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Repository
public class ReportDaoImpl implements ReportDao {

    //Note the JdbcTemplate variable name here
    private final JdbcTemplate myslJdbcTemplate; 

    @Autowired
    //Note the JdbcTemplate variable name here
    public ReportDaoImpl(JdbcTemplate myslJdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate; 
    }

    @Override
    public List<Report> findAll() {
        String sql = "SELECT report_id, title, threat_level, report_date, description, img_path, "
                            + "user.user_id, user_name FROM report "
                            + "INNER JOIN user ON report.user_id = user.user_id";

        List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql); 
……
```

You would need to update the repective JdbcTemplate for all the respective repository classes.

**Cheers and happy coding!**

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed advice! It's also extra help that you included code snippets as concrete examples :D

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define the same key multiple times in `application.properties` , one will override the other. That means if you need to use multiple datasources (for MySQL and H2),  you cannot relies on the `spring.datasource.xxx` in `application.properties`. Instead, define the two DataSource explicitly by yourself. See the official [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-two-datasources) for an example.

Also , `JdbcTemplate` will only be configured if :

- Only one `DataSource` defined
- If multiple `DataSource` are defined but only one `DataSource` is marked as `@Primary`, and it will configured just for this `@Primary` DataSource.

So that means after you define multiple DataSource , you have to mark the H2 one as `@Primary` such that the `JdbcTemplate` will be auto configured for it only to ensure that your existing `JDBCTempalte` related codes still interact with H2 but not MySQL.

By the way, there is no advantages to use multiple database for a simple CRUD app. You will encounter issues if you want to have a transaction which cover the data from multiple databases. I suggest you only choose one for such a simple app.

*(Also see my related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61172378/339637) for more detail)*

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Yeah what you point out makes sense. It's more difficult to manage two different databases than just one databse. I also appreciate the links you shared :)